# get value referencing key with Marshal

Tags: ios, swift, unmarshalling

The project is using [Marshal](https://github.com/utahiosmac/Marshal).

And I have a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
{"Stuff": 
   [
      {"Key": "SomeKey", "Value": "4056"},
      {"Key": "SomeOtherKey", "Value": "18"}
   ]
 }
```

Now I want to get the content of the `"Value"` where the `"Key"` is `"SomeKey"` (In this case it would be `"4056"`).

Does anyone know how to do it with this library?

Comment: If you are on Swift 4, consider `JSONDecoder / JSONEncoder`

Comment: @CodeDifferent That's what I though, but I just have to extend a rather big system by only one variable (that of course is different than anything else)

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, no parser can get around that

Comment: Ups, my bad, corrected (It is correct in the real code, please don't mind errors I may have introduced by manually writing the JSON)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is having the same problem, this is the only way I found:

I created a class to unmarshal all those items:

```
extension KeyValue: Unmarshaling {
    internal init(object: MarshaledObject) throws {
        self.name = try object <| "Key"
        self.value = try object <| "Value"
    }
}
```

and then filtered the one I needed:

```
let stuff: [KeyValue]
var someKey: String? {
   return stuff.first(where: { $0.name == "SomeKey" })?.value
}
```

(I guess there is no easy way to do this with Marshal)